# Active tab border bottom under the div instead in the div

Tags: html, css, margin

I have made a tab wrapper with 2 tabs. Under the tabs I have a `div` with content.

This is my code:

```css
.tab-wrapper {
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 17px;
  background-color: aqua;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table-cell;
}

.content {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.role-tab {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 19px;
}

.role-tab>p {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.role-tab-active {
  border-bottom: 3px #108DE7 solid;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-wrapper">
  <div class="role-tab role-tab-active">
    <p>Role tab 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="role-tab">
    <p>Role tab 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

The styling and everything are working good. Now I want to add some `padding-top` so the `border-bottom` will go under the `div`. This is a screenshot what I want:

[image: Screenshot]

I want that the `border-bottom` goes **under** the `div` instead of **in** the `div`.

I have tried `margin-top`, `padding-top` and `top`, but it didn't work

How can I achieve when the tab is active that the `border-bottom` goes under the `div` instead inside it?

Comment: try to add margin:0 to your p tag inside content. have added a reset css in your project?

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ckqzru3m/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the `margin-bttom: -3px;` for the active class and its done :

```
.role-tab-active {
    margin-bottom:-3px;
    border-bottom: 3px #108DE7 solid;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

see below snippet :

```css
.tab-wrapper {
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 17px;
    background-color: aqua;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: table-cell; 
}

.content{    
    background-color: aqua;
}

.role-tab {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 19px;
    margin-bottom:-3px;
}

    .role-tab > p {
        display: table-cell;
        height: 50px;
        overflow: visible;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
    }

.role-tab-active {
    margin-bottom:-3px;
    border-bottom: 3px #108DE7 solid;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-wrapper">
    <div class="role-tab role-tab-active">
        <p>Role tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="role-tab">
        <p>Role tab 2</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! This is a working example. I also need to add `margin-bottom` to the `Role-tab` class, because when the tab is active the text is not on the same line any more.

Comment: @Fearcoder haven't notice that thnx for correction :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't move borders via padding and margin. It's not an element but part of the element.

Give the `.tab-wrapper` a static height instead of default `auto`. Whatever the size of your border, the containing div will adjust to it instead, so we give it a static height to allow overflow. And then make it `display:flex`.

```
.tab-wrapper {
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 17px;
    background-color: aqua;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex; 
    height: 50px;
}
```

You can see that both the parent and tab items are of `50px` height, but that's not really the case when rendered. `box-sizing: content-box` being the default css property, your official active role tab height is `53px`, thus, overflowing the div by `3px` and giving the border an "under the div" effect

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c5u3wzv2/5/